# Community-detection algorithm to use to divide large network (200k nodes) into few (~5) communities

Tags: r, graph-theory, igraph

I have a large moderately dense network (50k nodes, 300k edges) and want to divide this into few (5-10) communities, based on how densely connected the nodes are.

I've been looking into the algorithms available in R's `igraph`-package and while they do what I want in principle, they all seem ill-suited for such large networks (e.g. `igraph_community_optimal_modularity`) or they provide no means of pre-specifying the number of communites. Applying those yields way too many communites (e.g., `igraph_community_fastgreedy` comes up with 60).

**Question**:
How (ideally with igraph and R) can I divide the graph into a pre-specified small number of communitities, in a computationally effcient way?

Comment: Are the current statistics of your graph correct? 200k nodes with 300k edges is an *extremely* sparse graph by most standards. Assuming you drop nodes with no edges, this means the majority of your nodes only have one edge.

Comment: You're right, this is the result of a lot of isolates which I can drop. The main network I care about is denser. I updated the numbers

Answer (score 2):

I've succeeded in similar problems using Newman's modularity via power iteration. The algorithm is very simple: bisect the graph until you have five clusters. This consumes only five rounds of graph bisection, implying that you only need five rounds of power iteration.

Newman's paper outlines how to do it. M. E. J. Newman. "[Modularity and community structure in networks](https://www.pnas.org/content/103/23/8577)." *PNAS*. June 6, 2006.

At the final stage you might have to make a choice about which bisections in order to optimize modularity subject to the desired number of clusters. This means you might have to commit to more bisections, which you later discard, because they offer suboptimal improvement.

If you really need to optimize it, notice that after each bisection, Newman's modularity applies a rank-1 update to our matrix. We can't leverage the Bunch-Nielsen-Sorensen result, because we don't have the full decomposition, but we can get an *approximation* of it. See Roy Mitz, Nir Sharon, and Yoel Shkolnisky. "[Symmetric rank-one updates from partial spectrum with an application to out-of-sample extension](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.02774.pdf)"

---

Since you're using R, power iteration could be slower than using an R interface into a compiled eigenvalue solver like ARPACK. Since Newman's modularity only needs the eigenvector to the largest eigenvalue, you can request the *truncated* solution, which will take less time to compute.

Comment: Great, that sounds like it does what I want. Any details on how you bisected the graph? Any simple way to use built in methods of igraph?

Comment: I just wrote the code myself. It's not too involved. Newman's paper describes how to bisect graphs using power iteration.